# Slightly revised version of submitted paper two days afterwards: will the editor be annoyed?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

so, I submitted a paper to a reasonably good journal, last week. The journal requires that the paper is formatted in a specific way (.tex class style provided by them). I did this, and saved the file in a different folder, to differentiate it from the version that I uploaded to my website.

However, when I sent the file to the editor (there is no submission system, just e-mail the editor), I sent the wrong version. That is, I sent the unformatted version. That wouldn't be too bad though. The thing is that the formatted version contains some slight improvements to exposition (and a slight title change..). So I decided to e-mail the editor with the new version, right after he acknowledged receipt of my previous manuscript.

I then realized that sending this to him would probably annoy the hell out of him, who is a recognized busy guy. Is this really a problem? I am really freaked out that this will create a problem with my submission.. I don't know whether acknowledging receipt means that he actually sent it to a referee already.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Unfortunately I am not sure whether we can answer your question with something other than a *maybe.* We cannot know how this particular journal and editor are ticking. What you could ask about, however, is the best etiquette in this situation, i.e., whether you should send yet another e-mail or not.

Comment: I do not see any possible reason why this would create an issue with your submission. Would the editor be slightly annoyed? Perhaps. Will it really make the editor reject your paper? RUN AWAY FROM THAT JOURNAL.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft thanks for the welcome message. I know it's a bit vague, I was just wondering if anyone else had experienced a similar situation. The journal is a serious math journal (not top level but good generalist journal).

Comment: @dgraziotin I agree. If the problem arises right away I can just go for another journal. But I don't want to have to wait several weeks for this.. anyway, we'll see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The more you wait the harder it gets to do that, there could be a pipeline that is already in progress. I suggest you send a nice email asking if there is a possibility to do this, and show that you would appreciate if he/she accepts the slightly updated attached version as the final version.

Do not worry about making the editor mad, he/she took responsibility for taking care of this and should be prepared for and expect to deal with such situations. If you want to maintain a good relationship with this editor (in case you know him/her personally), then maybe you should weight the values of: your relationship with the editor vs the quality of the final version. Personally I would go for the latter, but this is your call.

Comment: If you have a personal or professional relationship with the editor, that is all the more reason for them to help you rather than being upset.

Comment: Thanks! Well I already sent an e-mail with the new version.. that was my main problem. The old version is good enough, but I rushed into sending the new one without thinking it would probably be a bit annoying.. I will see if he responds sometimes this week, hopefully he'll be all right!

Comment: @dbluesk don't worry and celebrate the fact that you are done with your submission instead :)

Comment: @MohamedKhamis probably what I'll try to do :)